# when in X11: how to disable switching tty with Ctrl-Fn and Alt-Fn

Tags: ubuntu, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, tty, startx

It's super annoying that when I'm in X11 session Ctrl-F[1-12] and Alt-F[1-12] switches Linux virtual tty. How to disable it? (Ctrl-Alt-F[1-12] should work).

I'm using `startx` to start X11 session with *i3wm* (I don't know if it matters, but AFAIR when I was using display manager and KDE there was no such problem).

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal (within X11 is ok): `sudo kbd_mode -s`

(see also: [question at askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805793/how-can-i-disable-the-virtual-terminal-switching-shortcut-keys-in-x))

For me, that solved the problem.